# How to Port or Convert existing Windows Store App(Metro Style) to Desktop App?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, desktop-application

I have an existing App in Windows store(Metro Style)[XAML,C#]. I would like to convert this to Desktop(Ultra-book enabled ) and upload in to the Intel AppUp Store.
The application uses GPS and call several web API for certain features.

I there any tool to covert? or how could i port this app to Ultra-book enabled desktop app.?

Please provide step by step help or link..

Answer (score 0):

I would check with Intel what APIs they provide for AppUp. I am almost sure though that there are no tools for this and you just need to solve it on a case by case basis.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any tool to convert it for you. Based on my experience with Intel AppUp, if you can extract your metro app functionality and create a normal desktop application for it, you should be able to submit the app in the AppUp store.

You will have to create a msi package for your desktop app and the msi should create a desktop shortcut which can launch your app. The appUp guys somehow figure out the shortcut target and can launch the app from the AppUp client itself. You will also have to take care of uninstallation from the appup interface.