# Converting Windows Store App to Desktop App

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-store-apps

I am working on a product for Windows 8. I got GUI prepared by third company for Windows Store Application. However the libraries, that another company prepared, are not compatible with Windows Store Application. 
Is it possible to convert GUI, so it will not be Windows Store App anymore, but normal desktop WPF application?

Comment: Did you tried to search? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13243891/how-to-port-or-convert-existing-windows-store-appmetro-style-to-desktop-app

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any tool that will convert the project and give it to you.

If you create a new WPF project though and add all the files from the Windows Store project in it, most of your code(especially C#) should work.

Stuff which you will need to replace will be controls like GridView/ListView/AppBar and other specific Store controls. Other stuff like Grids/Stackpanels/Buttons etc. should work without any problems.